# Passing Arguments to nested functions in Swift

Tags: swift4

I'm taking a course on Closures and leading up to that is an understanding of nested functions.  I find the following example confusing.  You assign the nested function to a variable:

```
let person = personInTheHouse()
```

The variable is called as follows:

```
print(person(“playing cricket”)) // prints “The person is playing cricket.”
```

We are passing a String ("playing cricket") to the function.  What I can't wrap my head around is the function does not have a string as a parameter.  That is what I'm not understanding.

```
func personInTheHouse() -> ((String) -> String) {
```

Full code:

```
func personInTheHouse() -> ((String) -> String) {

    func doProcess(process: String) -> (String) { // nested function
         return “The person is \(process).”
    }

    return doProcess // or return doProcess(process:)
}

let person = personInTheHouse()
print(person(“playing cricket”)) // prints “The person is playing cricket.”
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mistaking with this:

> You assign the nested function to a variable:
>
> ```
> let person = personInTheHouse()
> ```

`personInTheHouse` is a nested function, but `personInTheHouse()` is the result of applying `()` to `personInTheHouse`, its return type is `(String) -> String`.

So, the type of `person` is `(String) -> String`, a normal (non-nested) function. It **has** a parameter of `String`, and you can pass a String `“playing cricket”` to `person`.

---

Inside your `personInTheHouse`, referencing function name without parameters like `doProcess` (or `doProcess(process:)`) represents the function itself as a closure. But adding actual parameter like `personInTheHouse()` represents the result of the function call.

Answer (score 0):

`personInTheHouse` is function that takes no argument and returns another function. When you write:

```
let person = personInTheHouse()
```

`person` is a function too. What kind of function is it? If you read the definition of `personInTheHouse`, you see that it returns `doProcess`, a function that takes a `String` and returns a `String`. So `person == doProcess` — it takes a `String` and returns a `String`.

That why you can write

```
print(person("playing cricket"))
```

Comment: So you assign a nested function to a variable.  The "top" function doesn't take a parameter, but the nested one does.

So you can pass an argument through the variable and it will be "received" as a parameter by the nested function?  So confusing.

Comment: The idea here is functions are first-class objects and you can pass them around in variables too